# discord.js my code isn't working, in the terminal it says typeError but I don't know what went wrong

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, discord.js

this is the code [image: picture]
I wanted to make an embed message when someone does the command -help it would bring out my contact info and the commands but it is not working, I have followed along this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7eZY-SBmf8
I have commented and asked him what went wrong but it looks like he doesn't respond to anyone.

update; [image: new code] but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning.

I think you just have to replace `.setFields` with `.addFields`. I would recommend you to read the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/) for more easier problems like that.

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) is the documentation for your problem.
And [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) is the documentation of MessageEmbed's in general.

Here is a sentence that I always think about when using MessageEmbed's:

> Every Component uses .set, except fields, they use .add

Comment: i have updated my code, can you please check mu update in the post, I have tried what it said but it is still giving me a terminal error

Comment: @NayeemPatwary in line 13 you have an empty value. Remove that or put something into `value: ""`.